# Database Query Help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, outer-join

So this is the DB that I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvSOj.jpg

It has been a while since the last time I worked with a MySQL DB, so I had a few issues that I need to solve.

First of all, I need to write a query that can show me both the name of the student and the class where they are registered at. I was trying some things with WHERE, but I was getting lost a lot.

SOLUTION: Using JOIN is the way to go since you need to connect 3 tables.

Comment: please share sample data with create table and insert data scripts. Image will not work. Also, one question per post.

Comment: Ask your other questions in a separate post.

Comment: You tagged ```outer join``` but that would only be used if you want students that have no corresponding class and/or classes which have no corresponding student.  You would need to specify that requirement.  If you want only the matches stick to ```[INNER] JOIN```, where the ```INNER``` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the first question.  We have a many to many relationship where student_class links each student_id with class_id, but the names are stored in the linked student table and class table.  So we need to join all three tables.

```
SELECT student.name, class.name
  FROM student
  JOIN student_class
    ON student.id = student_class.student_id
  JOIN class
    ON class.id = student_class.class_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inner join student table with class_registration table based on studentID and then join class_registration table with class table based on classID.

```
SELECT student.Name, class.ClassName
  FROM student
  inner join class_registration 
    ON student.id = class_registration.StudentId
 inner join class
    ON class.classid = class_registration.ClassId
;
```